# Java, jar dependency issue

Tags: java, jar

I am creating a new maven my.jar. This has dependency on another jar A.jar(V1.0).
Service B also has dependency on both A.jar(V1.0) and my.jar.

Now, Service B has A.jar twice, I am getting exceptions like this during run time,

deployment failed due to 
org.apache.geronimo.gbean.InvalidConfigurationException: Could not load class com.abc.xyz.geronimo.PaypalHttpsConnectorGBean

how can this be fixed?
Can't a service have two xyz.jar with same or different versions?

Comment: try to run `mvn dependency:tree` - you will get helpful info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maven supports transitive dependencies.
my.jar -> A

b->A
b->M

this shows that the first dependency is not necessary since your second dependency(b->M) would transitively give you A also
so i suggest removing you B.jar 's dependency to A.jar and keep only its dependency to my.jar

Comment: since my.jar is owned by me, and b.jar is owned by a different team, I cannot do that. I am wondering how this can be supported with out errors

Comment: maybe you can add <scope>provided</scope> to your A dependency in your my project pom.xml

Comment: you can use the exclude or the optional tags in your pom file.http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html